# How to solve Receive error: 10053 connection was aborted by the software in your host machine for folding@home?

Tags: windows-10, connection, configure, folding-at-home

I wanted to follow [Nvidia's call to action to donate unused GPU computing power to fight against COVID-19](https://twitter.com/NVIDIAGeForce/status/1238496311776653312?s=20) and installed the [Folding@home Client at Version 7.5.1](https://foldingathome.org/start-folding/) on a Windows 10 x64 machine.

My logs are full of messages that read:

```
ERROR:Receive error: 10053: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

---

That's the start part of my log:

```
22:00:41:           Time: 13:06:32
22:00:41:     Repository: Git
22:00:41:       Revision: 4705bf53c635f88b8fe85af7675557e15d491ff0
22:00:41:         Branch: master
22:00:41:       Compiler: Visual C++ 2008
22:00:41:        Options: /TP /nologo /EHa /wd4297 /wd4103 /Ox /MT
22:00:41:       Platform: win32 10
22:00:41:           Bits: 32
22:00:41:           Mode: Release
22:00:41:******************************* System ********************************
22:00:41:            CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor
22:00:41:         CPU ID: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2
22:00:41:           CPUs: 16
22:00:41:         Memory: 15.95GiB
22:00:41:    Free Memory: 11.42GiB
22:00:41:        Threads: WINDOWS_THREADS
22:00:41:     OS Version: 6.2
22:00:41:    Has Battery: false
22:00:41:     On Battery: false
22:00:41:     UTC Offset: 1
22:00:41:            PID: 15596
22:00:41:            CWD: C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\FAHClient
22:00:41:             OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
22:00:41:        OS Arch: AMD64
22:00:41:           GPUs: 1
22:00:41:          GPU 0: Bus:38 Slot:0 Func:0 AMD:5 Ellesmere XT [Radeon RX
22:00:41:                 470/480/570/580]
22:00:41:           CUDA: Not detected: Failed to open dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll': The
22:00:41:                 specified module could not be found.
22:00:41:
22:00:41:OpenCL Device 0: Platform:0 Device:0 Bus:38 Slot:0 Compute:1.2 Driver:3004.7
22:00:41:  Win32 Service: false
22:00:41:***********************************************************************
```

---

I am now also seeing errors of the form:

```
14:31:47:ERROR:WU02:FS00:Exception: Could not get IP address for assign1.foldingathome.org: No such host is known.
```

Comment: I know it's cliché, but when either my CPU or GPU is sitting idle for too long, I get a lot of mileage from pausing and restarting the FAH Client. Or restarting the computer. That seems to prompt the client to try downloading again, and sometimes it finally works.

Comment: Note that Rosetta@Home also has COVID-related projects, if you get fed up with FAH. Don't give up on helping in *some* way just because FAH is overwhelmed. There's plenty of work (units) to do!

Answer (score 1):

Just wait and let the application idle. At one point, you will get work units.

(Additionally, it may help to restart the application in order to force a try of a download.)

[Folding@Home announced via twitter](https://twitter.com/foldingathome/status/1239673282565214208?s=20):

> Why has my machine not received any work units (WUs)?
>
> We have been overwhelmed with support and donations, so our servers
>   had to suddenly accommodate a large number of returned WUs. We are
>   working on expanding our memory. Please bear with us as we address
>   this surge.(3/8)

I let the application idle for hours, and at one point it took three CPU-bound tasks (one at a time, idling in between). Starting today, it took one GPU-bound job.

I assume the error message relates more to the local webinterface and is of no indication that the application itself is misconfigured.

---

```
18:55:53:WU00:FS01:Starting
18:55:53:WU00:FS01:Running FahCore: "C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient/FAHCoreWrapper.exe" C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\FAHClient\cores/cores.foldingathome.org/v7/win/64bit/Core_22.fah/FahCore_22.exe -dir 00 -suffix 01 -version 705 -lifeline 19848 -checkpoint 15 -gpu-vendor amd -opencl-platform 0 -opencl-device 0 -gpu 0
18:55:53:WU00:FS01:Started FahCore on PID 25228
18:55:53:WU00:FS01:Core PID:24632
18:55:53:WU00:FS01:FahCore 0x22 started
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:*********************** Log Started 2020-03-16T18:55:54Z ***********************
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:*************************** Core22 Folding@home Core ***************************
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Type: 0x22
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Core: Core22
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:    Website: https://foldingathome.org/
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:  Copyright: (c) 2009-2018 foldingathome.org
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:     Author: John Chodera <john.chodera@choderalab.org> and Rafal Wiewiora
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:             <rafal.wiewiora@choderalab.org>
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Args: -dir 00 -suffix 01 -version 705 -lifeline 25228 -checkpoint 15
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:             -gpu-vendor amd -opencl-platform 0 -opencl-device 0 -gpu 0
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:     Config: <none>
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:************************************ Build *************************************
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:    Version: 0.0.2
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Date: Dec 6 2019
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Time: 21:30:31
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22: Repository: Git
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:   Revision: abeb39247cc72df5af0f63723edafadb23d5dfbe
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:     Branch: HEAD
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:   Compiler: Visual C++ 2008
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:    Options: /TP /nologo /EHa /wd4297 /wd4103 /Ox /MT
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:   Platform: win32 10
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Bits: 64
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       Mode: Release
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:************************************ System ************************************
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:        CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:     CPU ID: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:       CPUs: 16
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:     Memory: 15.95GiB
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Free Memory: 3.10GiB
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:    Threads: WINDOWS_THREADS
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22: OS Version: 6.2
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Has Battery: false
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22: On Battery: false
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22: UTC Offset: 1
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:        PID: 24632
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:        CWD: C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\FAHClient\work
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:         OS: Windows 10 Pro
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:    OS Arch: AMD64
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:********************************************************************************
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Project: 11744 (Run 0, Clone 6316, Gen 6)
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Unit: 0x000000098ca304f15e6bc433d4c43cac
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Reading tar file core.xml
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Reading tar file integrator.xml
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Reading tar file state.xml
18:55:54:WU00:FS01:0x22:Reading tar file system.xml
18:55:55:WU00:FS01:0x22:Digital signatures verified
18:55:55:WU00:FS01:0x22:Folding@home GPU Core22 Folding@home Core
18:55:55:WU00:FS01:0x22:Version 0.0.2
18:56:10:WU00:FS01:0x22:Completed 0 out of 1000000 steps (0%)
18:56:10:WU00:FS01:0x22:Temperature control disabled. Requirements: single Nvidia GPU, tmax must be < 110 and twait >= 900
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, when you install the client, you are presented with a Windows Security Alert, like in this picture:

[image: Windows Firewall Sample]

You need to allow access for  both networks. That is, the "Private networks, such as my home or work network" needs to be checked.  So, if anyone encounters this error a hassle free solution is to fully uninstall it and install it again. Otherwise, go to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall > Allowed apps > Change settings and allow fahclient for both networks.

Comment: I'm not sure "public networks" is actually required. This error persists on home network too (when public is not active). Anyways, you don't need to reinstall to try it. In Windows, for example, goto Firewall and then click "Advanced Security". Find `fahclient` in list for inbound and outbound. Double click the entry, then hit the "Advanced" tab. Here you can add both "Domain" and/or "Public" attribs to the rule. If the error persists, be sure to turn back off those attribs.